# Able to start chrome from path but can't control it in pywinauto

Tags: python, browser-automation, pywinauto

I had tried this code:

```
from pywinauto import Application
app = Application().start("chrome")
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1038, in start
    (h_process, _, dw_process_id, _) = win32process.CreateProcess(
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1052, in start
    raise AppStartError(message)
pywinauto.application.AppStartError: Could not create the process "chrome"
Error returned by CreateProcess: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

So I tried this instead:

```
from pywinauto import Application
app = Application().start(r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe")
```

This launched google however, I can't control it. When I run this code:

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application().start(r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe")
app.NewTab.Edit.set_text("A link")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 250, in __resolve_control
    ctrl = wait_until_passes(
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 379, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 261, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 203, in __get_ctrl
    dialog = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**criteria[0]))
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 84, in find_element
    elements = find_elements(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 305, in find_elements
    elements = findbestmatch.find_best_control_matches(best_match, wrapped_elems)
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 536, in find_best_control_matches
    raise MatchError(items = name_control_map.keys(), tofind = search_text)
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'NewTab' in 'dict_keys([])'
```

I don't understand this error at all. I had searched stack overflow and tried this code:

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application().start("chrome.exe --force-renderer-accessibility")
app.NewTab.Edit.set_text("A link")
```

but it yielded the same results. I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
>>> app = Application().start("chrome.exe --force-renderer-accessibility")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1038, in start
    (h_process, _, dw_process_id, _) = win32process.CreateProcess(
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1052, in start
    raise AppStartError(message)
pywinauto.application.AppStartError: Could not create the process "chrome.exe --force-renderer-accessibility"
Error returned by CreateProcess: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
>>> app.NewTab.Edit.set_text("A link")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
>>> app = Application().start("chrome.exe --force-renderer-accessibility")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1038, in start
    (h_process, _, dw_process_id, _) = win32process.CreateProcess(
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1052, in start
    raise AppStartError(message)
pywinauto.application.AppStartError: Could not create the process "chrome.exe --force-renderer-accessibility"
Error returned by CreateProcess: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
```

Also I'm using python 3.10.0 so is this a bug of my version?

Comment: What is that you looking from pywinauto to automate chrome? Why don't you try selenium instead of pywinato? pywinauto is for desktop application AFAIK, not for browsers.

Comment: @Dev but selenium requires driver installation

Comment: It does NOT, it just need it in the path and you can handle that dynamically using driver manager.

Comment: @Dev could you please elaborate a bit, i did not understand

Comment: Check the sample snippet of webdriver manager here  -http://allselenium.info/browser-drivers-with-python-webdrivermanager/

Comment: @Dev but how do i type text then using selenium, there are not any specific results on google

Comment: It is clearly given on the link, `driver.get()` function will do that for you, it will accept the URL and navigate to it, I assume you want to type the URL in the address bar of the chrome.

Comment: @Dev but it doesn't end there. This was just an example. I want to press keys and send keys to the browser window's webpage's entry fields. I did find some results but they all require the browser window to be maximized, however, I wish keeping the window minimized.

Comment: you can try headless mode using selenium, by the way pywinauto will not do that for you so your tool selection is incorrect in first place. And hence your question stands irrelevant IMO. Also you can refer to selenium documentation, it all given over there